# Cannot read property 'login' of undefined

Tags: node.js, javascript

Работаю в node.js. Пытаюсь передать данные из формы в app:

```
app.get('/add', function(res, req, next) {
var record = new Record({
   text: req.body.login,
   login: req.session.login
});
record.save(function(err, user, affected){
    res.redirect('/main', {
        login: req.session.login
    });
});
});
```

Выскакивает такая вот ошибка:

> Cannot read property 'login' of
> undefined.

В форме и поле ввода все прописано, имя, метод и т.д. Самое интересное, что я делаю все то же самое немного ранее, все работает. Возможно, это связано с `app.use(express.bodyParser());`. Хотя через req.query.login тоже не работает.

Comment: Не установлено свойство "login".  
Почему - не знаю, у меня с Node.Js плохие отношения :)

Comment: не свойство логин не установлено, а свойство session.

Comment: @eicto, я перевёл ему ошибку, а не трассировал ошибку, т.к. с Node.Js плохие отношения :)

Comment: неправильно перевел

Cannot read property 'login' **of** undefined

кто тут undefined ? не login :) вот смотрите

    var req={};
    req.login;
    req.session.login; /* ошибка здесь, а не выше*/

Comment: @eicto, ух докопался :)  
ОК, пусть будет так, хотя если включить режим зануды... да ну, не хочу.

Comment: ну чего тут включать, этож специально ошибка так сделана чтобы безболезненно обращаться к несуществующим ключам, чтобы можно было таки написать `req.session = {login: 'user'};` а не замораживать ключи объекта при создании...

Comment: нет не свойства login... тот объект, к которому идет вызов свойства login **is undefined**, попробуй почувствовать разницу (у него вообще никаких свойств нет) и мало того, установить это свойство невозможно, т.к. `req.session.login="user"` вызовет точно такую же ошибку.

Comment: Да понятно, что объекта нету!  
Но "отсутствие свойства" и "отсутствие объекта, чтобы взять свойство" в данном случае не противоречат друг другу и приводят к одному - `login` хрен достанешь.

Comment: Господа, спасибо всем. Ошибка была, как всегда, банальна - я ошибся в порядке объявления req и res, их нужно поменять местами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ: перепутаны переменные req и res. Конечно же, входящие параметры идут первыми в списке аргументов. Правильный вариант:

```
app.get('/add', function(req, res, next) {
var record = new Record({
   text: req.body.login,
   login: req.session.login
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что вы используете `express` для создания веб-приложения. В последней версии `express` была произведена чистка и многие встроенные вещи "перекочевали" в плагины. Так, например, для включения поддержки сессий вам нужно установить модуль `express-session`, а затем в коде

```
var session = require('express-session');
...

app.use(session({secret: 'my-secret'}));
```

После этого вы можете использовать `req.session` в своих маршрутах.

https://github.com/expressjs/session